# How do I save any string in the users browser? is this useful?

Tags: php, html

I know that through cookies or something like that you can save things in the user's PC/browser. It would be useful for me to save the users location after he typed it, so I can adjust all the info accordingly. My question is, what is the best way to do that and how long is the info saved? And finally if I wanted to save for example the word "pizza" and access it later how do I do it?

Thanks. I know it's a lot and all very noobish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple example:

### page1.php

```
<?php
  setcookie('favorite_food', 'pizza');
?>
I just set your favorite food to "pizza". <a href="page2.php">Want to see?</a>
```

### page2.php

```
Your favorite food is <?php echo $_COOKIE['favorite_food'] ?>.
```

The function for setting is [`setcookie`](http://php.net/setcookie). You provide a name for the cookie, the value (contents), when it should expire (`time() + $number_of_seconds_until_it_should_expire`), and then some other options regarding where on your site this cookie can be accessed. If you give no expire time, most browsers will delete the cookie once the browser is closed. [The PHP setcookie documentation](http://php.net/setcookie) is much more detailed and is a good starting point for any more specific questions you may have.

It can later be accessed via `$_COOKIE['name_you_used_when_setting']`.

A general note: always remember that, when dealing with cookies, you can't trust the user not to change them or delete them at any time. Use them *only* for convenience, and *never* for something like `setcookie('user_is_admin', 1)` or `setcookie('user_is_banned', 1)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the complete explanation. I'll try it later today.

Answer (score 1):

Save it in a cookie. It's saved for as long as you specify, unless the user clears their cookies. As for setting it, take a look at PHP's [`setcookie()` function](http://php.net/setcookie)